# Error : DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN Google Cloud Platform, WordPress site, Custom Domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns

My name-servers are correct and I did not change anything but my site suddenly started showing `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. I am using Google Cloud Platform to host the site - "Wordpress: Click to deploy". My domain is : `Example.cf`.

Comment: what do you get with `curl -i http://yourdomain.com`? Don't post the output. Review any errors and fix them. The error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN means that your domain name is not resolving. This is probably an incorrect mapping from the DNS name to the IP address of the server.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly like a DNS configuration error, also note your question is missing the information on DNS details. That is not a problem though, you can use `dig +trace` to find the name servers.

You domain is not resolving to an IP address, therefore there is no way for users to hit your wordpress site.

```
$dig example.cf +short
$dig www.example.cf +short
```

Both queries returned nothing. Tracing your dns returns Google's name servers, and directly querying those name servers returns  nothing.

```
example.cf.      300     IN      NS      ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
example.cf.      300     IN      NS      ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
example.cf.      300     IN      NS      ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
example.cf.      300     IN      NS      ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.

$dig @ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. example.cf. +short
```

Make sure to point your domain to the IP address of your web server. If you are using GCP cloud dns, use this link - https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart - to setup dns.